# "Line of code" in Japanese

Tags: words, counters, computing

I've been doing a bit of work with rendering 縦書き【たてがき】 in HTML, and was having a running internal monologue in Japanese about how things were progressing when I hit on a missing word: "line" as in "line of code".  Trying to think of possibilities I came up with 列【れつ】 or 線【せん】, but neither feels right.  Perhaps just the import ライン instead?  Can anyone shed some light on this?

For context, the sentence in question is

> 余計な＊を抜くと状況が直った。

Comment: What do you mean by 状況が直った? _circumstances were repaired_?

Comment: Pretty much.  Essentially that I had some extra lines of CSS, and when I pruned the unnecessary ones things started displaying properly.

Comment: Since you already accepted an answer for your question, you could ask a separate question about your sentence.

Comment: The answer covered the issue I was addressing; is there a problem with my wording in the sentence itself?

Comment: I think that the choices of 余計, 抜く, 状況 and 直る are somewhat unsuitable for your context. At the moment it sounds a bit like "The circumstances were repaired, when I extracted abundant lines." It's not that one can't follow the meaning, but the wording is not entirely natural.

Comment: I see.  In that case I guess I *will* offer it up as another question.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is it just me or do none of the answers or comments address the "of code" part of the phrase? Unless I'm mistaken I now know which term to use for "line" in this context but still don't know how to say the entire phrase (-:

Comment: Between experience and observations regarding the patterns so far, it appears that the "of code" part is left up to the context to represent, and that otherwise it's generally treated no differently from any other lines of text for purposes of enumeration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use 行 (ぎょう) for the lines (in a book chapter, a programming code, etc.), *no matter* whether the sentence is written horizontally (横書き) or vertically (縦書き).

For example, "Removing three lines from the CSS file" is as follows:

> CSSファイルから3行抜く