# Natural way of saying "Once you take away the unnecessary bits, it works"

Tags: word-choice

In my earlier question ["Line of code" in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/line-of-code-in-japanese) I was trying to figure out a word for the following sentence:

> 余計【よけい】な行【ぎょう】を抜く【ぬく】と状況【じょうきょう】が直った【なおった】。 "Once the unnecessary lines were removed, things worked properly."

In the exchange that followed, it was pointed out that while the intended meaning is discernible, it has a distinctly translated-into-Japanese feeling.  What is a better way of  expressing my intent per the translation above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「状況が直った」 sounds kind of informal and depending on who you are speaking to, it could sound a little bit unadultlike.  How about a 「状況が[改善]{かいぜん}した or された」?

「余計な」 would sound too colloquial here.  I would use 「[不要]{ふよう}な」 or 「[不必要]{ふひつよう}な」.

「抜く」 also sounds conversational.  You might go with 「[削除]{さくじょ}する」

Examples:

> 「不要な行を削除したところ、状況が改善した。」
>
> 「不要な行を削除したところ、状況に改善が見られた。」 ← My best TL.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem was more a matter of formality than being unnatural perhaps.  Setting 余計 aside, is this due mostly to the lack of 漢語 in my original sentence?

Comment: In short, yes.  I assumed this was for business and we use lots of on-reading words in business.